# how can i put an alarm on certain days of the week

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Hello friends that I developed an application Creating courses. I want to give notice when the time course.

So if you have classes Monday at 8 o'clock. 8 hours per week of class time came. I want to create a notification. I'm doing this with the alarmmanager and notification. I can give you one-time alarms. But somehow I could not repeat. Codes as follows. I will not try it because it is part of recevice.

```
private void alarmla() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=activity.openOrCreateDatabase("SINIFD",activity.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from ders", null);
    if(c.getCount()>0){
        c.moveToFirst();

            do {
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Toast.makeText(activity, c.getString(3).split(":")[0] + " " + c.getString(3).split(":")[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");

                notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                notificationIntent.putExtra("message", c.getString(1) + " dersi zamanı geldi. Kazanımlara ulaşmak için tıklayınız. İyi dersler.");
                notificationIntent.putExtra("gizli", c.getString(6));

                PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, c.getInt(0), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                Calendar timeOff = Calendar.getInstance();
                int days = Calendar.FRIDAY + (7 - timeOff.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // how many days until Sunday

                timeOff.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
                timeOff.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3).split(":")[0]));  //buraya 22 geliyor databaseden
                timeOff.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3).split(":")[1]));  //buraya 10 geliyor mesala
                timeOff.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                timeOff.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeOff.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, broadcast);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();

    }
    db.close();
    Toast.makeText(activity,"Vay be ayar ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

When there is no problem with the database of the adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget relaunch alarm manager after rebooting your mobile device!

Use broadcast receiver to catch this action

More about reboot : [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)